# vuex mutations setting state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am making a request to an api, that returns a response that looks likes,

```
{"quiz_history":{},"user":{"id":196,"nickname":"VuexTest3","login_code":"88988472","host":1,"room_id":46,"emoji":"/images/emojis/2.png","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:24:14","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:24:14"},"quiz":[{"id":1,"date_playable":"2019-10-15 00:00:00","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","questions":[{"id":1,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Velit sed sint consequatur iusto.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":1,"answer":"aut","correct":0,"question_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":2,"answer":"modi","correct":0,"question_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":3,"answer":"sunt","correct":1,"question_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":4,"answer":"mollitia","correct":0,"question_id":1,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":2,"quiz_id":1,"question":"In praesentium laboriosam molestiae voluptatem natus.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":5,"answer":"similique","correct":0,"question_id":2,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":6,"answer":"possimus","correct":0,"question_id":2,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":7,"answer":"dolorem","correct":1,"question_id":2,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":8,"answer":"labore","correct":0,"question_id":2,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":3,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Aut totam quia praesentium qui.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":9,"answer":"non","correct":0,"question_id":3,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":10,"answer":"aperiam","correct":0,"question_id":3,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":11,"answer":"et","correct":1,"question_id":3,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":12,"answer":"nihil","correct":0,"question_id":3,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":4,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Expedita porro et fuga in. Et quae fugiat accusantium sed corrupti.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":13,"answer":"fuga","correct":0,"question_id":4,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":14,"answer":"provident","correct":0,"question_id":4,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":15,"answer":"et","correct":1,"question_id":4,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":16,"answer":"soluta","correct":0,"question_id":4,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":5,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Explicabo rerum cumque dolor eius corporis.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":17,"answer":"aut","correct":0,"question_id":5,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":18,"answer":"dolorum","correct":0,"question_id":5,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":19,"answer":"beatae","correct":1,"question_id":5,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":20,"answer":"laudantium","correct":0,"question_id":5,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":6,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Adipisci ducimus molestias in et.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":21,"answer":"voluptatem","correct":0,"question_id":6,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":22,"answer":"earum","correct":0,"question_id":6,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":23,"answer":"optio","correct":1,"question_id":6,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":24,"answer":"velit","correct":0,"question_id":6,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":7,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Aliquam atque et dolores quidem.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":25,"answer":"optio","correct":0,"question_id":7,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":26,"answer":"aut","correct":0,"question_id":7,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":27,"answer":"nostrum","correct":1,"question_id":7,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":28,"answer":"ad","correct":0,"question_id":7,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":8,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Eos asperiores deleniti tempore ducimus quo voluptate.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":29,"answer":"tenetur","correct":0,"question_id":8,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":30,"answer":"enim","correct":0,"question_id":8,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":31,"answer":"consectetur","correct":1,"question_id":8,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":32,"answer":"assumenda","correct":0,"question_id":8,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":9,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Et et ratione aliquam dignissimos.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":33,"answer":"et","correct":0,"question_id":9,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":34,"answer":"maxime","correct":0,"question_id":9,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":35,"answer":"sit","correct":1,"question_id":9,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":36,"answer":"optio","correct":0,"question_id":9,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":10,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Rerum amet dolores inventore nemo rem sapiente provident.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":37,"answer":"praesentium","correct":0,"question_id":10,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":38,"answer":"maiores","correct":0,"question_id":10,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":39,"answer":"dicta","correct":1,"question_id":10,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":40,"answer":"iste","correct":0,"question_id":10,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":11,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Et qui aut ullam molestiae esse iste quis.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":41,"answer":"et","correct":0,"question_id":11,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":42,"answer":"ut","correct":0,"question_id":11,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":43,"answer":"aut","correct":1,"question_id":11,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":44,"answer":"laudantium","correct":0,"question_id":11,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":12,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Non sunt repellendus et aut quae.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":45,"answer":"consequatur","correct":0,"question_id":12,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":46,"answer":"ea","correct":0,"question_id":12,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":47,"answer":"occaecati","correct":1,"question_id":12,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":48,"answer":"saepe","correct":0,"question_id":12,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":13,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Numquam inventore amet vel at officiis. Minima sed temporibus ut aut.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":49,"answer":"dolor","correct":0,"question_id":13,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":50,"answer":"reprehenderit","correct":0,"question_id":13,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":51,"answer":"sint","correct":1,"question_id":13,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":52,"answer":"officia","correct":0,"question_id":13,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":14,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Iure qui consequatur corrupti consectetur quia voluptatem beatae.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":53,"answer":"tempora","correct":0,"question_id":14,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":54,"answer":"doloribus","correct":0,"question_id":14,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":55,"answer":"quas","correct":1,"question_id":14,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":56,"answer":"voluptas","correct":0,"question_id":14,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]},{"id":15,"quiz_id":1,"question":"Quis earum quia eos iste necessitatibus dolore.","created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","answers":[{"id":57,"answer":"et","correct":0,"question_id":15,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":58,"answer":"totam","correct":0,"question_id":15,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":59,"answer":"omnis","correct":1,"question_id":15,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"},{"id":60,"answer":"quam","correct":0,"question_id":15,"created_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23","updated_at":"2019-10-15 16:38:23"}]}]}]}
```

I want to set my state to match the response, I am doing it like this,

```
mutations: {
    setQuiz(state, payload) {
        state = {...payload.quiz};
    },
},
```

This is a module called quiz, so I was hoping that I would get something like, `state.quiz` with the contents of whatever the server responds with.

However after the mutation `state.quiz` is just empty. I cannot understand why.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vuex but knowing that it's JS, that response seems invalid. The outer object has no properties, but the array does. Perhaps you've simply reversed the bracket types, e.g. it should be `[ { ... } ]` instead of `{ [ ... ] }`? That said, I don't see a `.quiz` property anywhere.

Comment: With your edited question, it appears you're spreading the **value** of the `.quiz` property, which itself does not have another `quiz` property. If you wanted the `state` to be an object with a `quiz` property, I'd imagine you want `state = { quiz: {...payload.quiz} }` or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response the output you get is

```
{...paylad.quiz}
```

Output

```
{
0: {id: 1, date_playable: "2019-10-15 00:00:00", created_at: "2019-10-15 16:38:23", updated_at: "2019-10-15 16:38:23", questions: Array(15)}
}
```

Here your are having quiz in array format, when you do spread operator(...) inside an object ({}), it tried to create objects keys using array index and values as array value

Instead you can do

```
mutations: {
    setQuiz(state, payload) {
        state.quiz = payload.quiz;
    },
},
```